# Using DataStax search programmatically (DataStax driver or phantom)

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, phantom-dsl

Is there currently a way to use DataStax search from an application except with plain string queries / prepared statements?

If yes, is there an example / tutorial?

If no, are there plans to integrate this feature in the future?

Both DataStax or phantom DSL would be great.

Comment: I don't particularly know what you are referring to by Datastax search. If you mean the Solr powered part, we are working very hard to include that in our phantom-pro product, which supports all the premium features of DSE natively.

Comment: DSE Search does allow you to make Solr queries from CQL (see https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCql.html). Keep in mind that there are some advanced use-cases that are not supported yet.

Comment: @flavian - yes, I mean the Lucene/Solr indices. Good news then, looking forward to look into it. Do you happen to have an approximate GA date?

Comment: @CalebRackliffe - yes, exactly, this is what I mean with 'plain string'. I would generally prefer some sort of a higher level mapping like phantom or quill provide. Looks like there will be something in the near future.

Comment: Hi @kostja we are preparing for an end of june delivery of Solr and Lucene indexes being natively supported. Send me an email using my github email and I'll add you to the waiting list so you get notified automatically if you would like!